# System network broken, due to wrong installed driver

Tags: networking, drivers, connection, intel-wireless

In my search for fixing the issue I posted here, [How to set wifi driver settings to prefer 5 GHz channel above 2.4 GHz](https://askubuntu.com/questions/183525/how-to-set-wifi-driver-settings-to-prefer-5-ghz-channel-above-2-4-ghz), I thought that it might be a good idea to update the drivers.

I have a "Intel 82567LM Gigabit Network Connection" and "Intel Wifi Link 5100 AGN" I went to search for linux drivers. I then found this driver, http://downloadcenter.intel.com/Detail_Desc.aspx?agr=Y&DwnldID=15817&lang=eng&OSVersion=Linux*&DownloadType=Drivers. I installed it. Now after a reboot I find out my network connection is broken and can not get access to internet anymore. It seems the driver is incompatible :(

Now is it possible to fix this issue? Or might it better just to reinstall ubuntu?

Relevant images:
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With some help of a guy on ubuntuforums.org I fixed this issue. I had to reinstall the network manager.

> sudo apt-get install --reinstall network-manager

However due to the fact I had no internet on my OS I started up with ubuntu from USB where internet still worked and then downloaded the package from.

> http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/net/network-manager

The whole topic can be found at:

> http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2054615