# How do I require use of the 5 GHz band when connecting to a Wireless N access point?

Tags: wireless

What is says in the topic: there's a Wireless N access point to which I'd like to connect using the 5 GHz band exclusively. How does one accomplish this? Using the directive `band=a` in the connection configuration file in `/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections` doesn't seem to affect anything (`/var/log/syslog` still shows attempts by wpa_supplicant to connect using the 2.4 GHz band), and running `iwconfig wlan0 freq 5G` per [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/183525/how-to-set-wifi-driver-settings-to-prefer-5-ghz-channel-above-2-4-ghz) results in the following error:

```
Error for wireless request "Set Frequency" (8B04) :
    SET failed on device wlan0 ; Invalid argument.
```

[Edit] I'm hoping the answer won't depend on the hardware in use, but here's some information about the hardware, just in case:

System is an Asus ZenBook Prime UX31A-DB51, running Ubuntu 12.04.

lspci output:

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Ivy Bridge DRAM Controller (rev 09)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Ivy Bridge Graphics Controller (rev 09)
00:04.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Device 0153 (rev 09)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Panther Point USB xHCI Host Controller (rev 04)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Panther Point MEI Controller #1 (rev 04)
00:1a.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Panther Point USB Enhanced Host Controller #2 (rev 04)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation Panther Point High Definition Audio Controller (rev 04)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Panther Point PCI Express Root Port 1 (rev c4)
00:1c.1 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Panther Point PCI Express Root Port 2 (rev c4)
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Panther Point USB Enhanced Host Controller #1 (rev 04)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Panther Point LPC Controller (rev 04)
00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation Panther Point 6 port SATA Controller [AHCI mode] (rev 04)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation Panther Point SMBus Controller (rev 04)
00:1f.6 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Panther Point Thermal Management Controller (rev 04)
02:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Centrino Advanced-N 6235 (rev 24)
```

The driver for the wireless interface is `iwlwifi`.

Comment: This looks like something hardware specific, so what wireless card do you have, and what drivers do you have for it?

Comment: I'ld be looking at going around this one at setting the channel number instead to something only found in the 5Ghz band: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_WLAN_channels#5.C2.A0GHz_.28802.11a.2Fh.2Fj.2Fn.29.5B13.5D

Comment: Related: https://askubuntu.com/questions/183525/how-to-set-wifi-driver-settings-to-prefer-5-ghz-channel-above-2-4-ghz

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Using **iwlwifi on 12.10**,

> iwconfig wlan0 channel 36

or

> iwconfig wlan0 freq 5.18G

works

You MUST specify the channel (or exact corresponding frequency). Specfifying the frequency band (iow. just "5G") does not work.

Note that some dual-band/dual-radio access points (maybe only those of the "enterprise" category) can/should use "band steering" (aka. "frequency handoff"): the AP detects 5G-able clients and disconnect them from the 2.4G band to force them off to the 5G band. It may takes some time for this "trick" to take place, though.

Comment: of course, specify the channel/frequency that you have configured on your AP ;-)

Comment: Does not work for me. I get `SET failed on device wlp3s0 ; Device or resource busy.`

Comment: @Huygens bring your device down first `ifconfig wlp3s0 down`, set `iwconfig`, and bring it back up again

Comment: @naisanza thanks. Since then I had a new laptop, a newer Ubuntu and a newer WiFi AP, I can't tell which of these change(s) did the trick but now most of the time I'm on the 5GHz band automatically. But thanks anyway for the feedback.

Comment: Note that you can find out which channel is your 5GHz network with this: `iwlist wlan0 scanning | grep -C5 -i '\"my_network_name\"'`. **2.4GHz channels** include `01`, `02`, `03`, etc. through `11`, and **5GHz channels** are just `36`, `40`, `44`, and `48`. I first learned the `iwlist` command from here: https://askubuntu.com/a/631329/327339.

Comment: Also, this answer doesn't work at all for me. Note that I'm on Ubuntu 20.04 and have also followed [this answer here too](https://askubuntu.com/a/1271252/327339) to use `iwd` instead of `wpa_supplicant` so my 2.4Ghz would work at all on my new MU-MIMO EAP225-Outdoor long range wireless Access Point.