# Ubuntu 20.04 WiFi "No Networks" after latest automatic update today, 24 Aug. 2021

Tags: networking, wireless

On Ubuntu 20.04. The automatic updater popped up. I clicked to install updates like I have hundreds of times before over the years. It asked to restart. I said ok. Now, I have no WiFi:

[image]

In the top-right, the wifi shows up blank:

[image]

What do I do? I am posting this by getting internet through a wired Ethernet connection to the router in my kitchen.

Is there some way to roll back to just before the latest updates? Or, to just get the Wifi working?

---

Here are a few outputs in case they are somehow useful:

```
$ cat /etc/netplan/01-network-manager-all.yaml 
# Let NetworkManager manage all devices on this system
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: NetworkManager
```

```
$ lspci | grep -i network
02:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Wireless 8265 / 8275 (rev 78)
```

Bluetooth *does* still work. I can still connect my bluetooth headphones to the laptop just fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved. This got me back on the WiFi, so I'm considering it good enough. However, it undid [my solution to connect to a 2.4 GHz MU-MIMO router](https://askubuntu.com/a/1271252/327339), which now I can no longer connect to again (Ubuntu can connect to the 5 GHz network to this router, but not its 2.4 GHz network, even though every other device I own can connect to the 2.4 GHz network just fine). So, oh well; good enough.

If you find a better solution, however, by all means, please do post it.

### What did NOT work

I tried downloading the [latest Intel wireless driver](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/articles/000005511/wireless.html) for "Intel® Dual Band Wireless-AC 8265", extracting it, and copying it to "/lib/firmware" with `sudo cp iwlwifi-8265-22.ucode /lib/firmware`, then rebooting, to update the Intel wireless driver, and that did NOT work. No change.

### Solution: switch back from `iwd.service` to Ubuntu's default `wpa_supplicant.service`

I don't really know what `iwd.service` or `wpa_supplicant.service` are or mean, but I know how to change from one to the other. They seem to be daemons running in the background in Ubuntu which help find and connect to wifi networks.

**Ubuntu 20.04 by default comes with `wpa_supplicant.service` running. However, I disabled it here: [Ubuntu 19.10 won't connect to 2.4GHz wifi with TxBF, MU-MIMO enabled](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1196348/ubuntu-19-10-wont-connect-to-2-4ghz-wifi-with-txbf-mu-mimo-enabled/1271252#1271252.)**

So, **the solution was to re-enable it. The latest automatic updates on Ubuntu 20.04 *today* seem to have broken the `iwd.service` and it no longer works.** So, here is how to disable the `iwd.service` and switch back to the default `wpa_supplicant.service` which comes running on a default Ubuntu install:

```bsh
# 1. disable the wifi_backend.conf file where you set the backend to iwd
sudo mv /etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/wifi_backend.conf \
/etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/wifi_backend.conf.bak

# 2. Stop and disable the iwd service (this is persistent after reboots)
sudo systemctl stop iwd.service
sudo systemctl disable iwd.service

# 3. Enable and start the wpa_supplicant service (this is persistent after
# reboots)
sudo systemctl enable wpa_supplicant.service
sudo systemctl start wpa_supplicant.service

# 4. Restart NetworkManager service (this means you don't have to restart
# your computer for this to take effect--it just works immediately!)
systemctl restart network-manager.service
```

Done! Now my wifi works again, but on that one router of mine (TP-Link EAP225-Outdoor, which supports MU-MIMO) [I cannot connect to its 2.4 GHz network from Ubuntu anymore](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1196348/ubuntu-19-10-wont-connect-to-2-4ghz-wifi-with-txbf-mu-mimo-enabled/1271252#1271252). Oh well.

Note that the way I can tell `iwd.service` no longer works after this latest automatic update on Ubuntu 20.04 today is this:

1. My wireless quit working! No networks whatsoever show up!
2. When I run this: `sudo systemctl start iwd.service`, I get this error:

   > ```
   > Job for iwd.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
   > See "systemctl status iwd.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
   > ```

   And `systemctl status iwd.service` shows that it failed to start:

   > ```
   > ● iwd.service - Wireless service
   >      Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/iwd.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   >      Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Tue 2021-08-24 21:42:51 MST; 10s ago
   >     Process: 14813 ExecStart=/usr/libexec/iwd (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
   >    Main PID: 14813 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
   >
   > Aug 24 21:42:51 gabriel-Latitude-7490 systemd[1]: iwd.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter>
   > Aug 24 21:42:51 gabriel-Latitude-7490 systemd[1]: Stopped Wireless service.
   > Aug 24 21:42:51 gabriel-Latitude-7490 systemd[1]: iwd.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
   > Aug 24 21:42:51 gabriel-Latitude-7490 systemd[1]: iwd.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
   > Aug 24 21:42:51 gabriel-Latitude-7490 systemd[1]: Failed to start Wireless service.
   > ```