# Can't connect wifi Ubuntu 20.04.3

Tags: 20.04, iwlwifi

I have an Intel 7265 wireless adapter. Doing a bit of research I've run several lines in the terminal and now `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; rfkill list` gives:

```
    DeviceName: Intel Dual BandWireless-AC 7265 802.11 ac 1x1 WiFi + BT 4.0 Combo Adapter
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Dual Band Wireless-AC 7265 [8086:5010]
    Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi
0: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: yes
    Hard blocked: no
1: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

Network manager shows all networks in range. When I try to connect it prompts for the password, I enter it and it keeps asking for it until it stops trying to connect after a minute or two. I made sure the password is correct.

If I observe the connected devices my router shows while Network Manager tries to connect, I can see my laptop appears for a couple of seconds, disappears and repeats the cycle for the duration of the "Connecting" phase.

I followed this [answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1245268/ubuntu-keeps-booting-me-off-of-5ghz-wifi-network-and-prompting-for-password) with no luck.

**Update 1:** `sudo dmesg | grep -e wlo1 -e Network` gives [this](https://pastebin.ubuntu.com/p/2ynxMmp8GF/).

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/133364/discussion-on-question-by-jaime-caballero-cant-connect-wifi-ubuntu-20-04-3).