# Force Wi-Fi connection to 2.4GHZ in Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS

Tags: networking, wireless, wireless-access-point

I am a complete Linux NOOB, so please elaborate on your answers as if you were explaining to your non-computer-literate elder relative.

I am running multiple instances of Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS on mini computers such as Intel NUCs, Gigabytes, and Beelinks, in a remote kiosk setting. The Wi-Fi coverage at the locations is pretty poor, and sometimes I suspect that the computers prefer to 5GHz, but being inside a metal kiosk case, it may not penetrate as well, so I am looking to run a test to force the Wi-Fi to 2.4GHz.

I tried following the steps in this previous question here on Ask Ubuntu on [forcing to 5GHZ](https://askubuntu.com/questions/183525/how-to-set-wifi-driver-settings-to-prefer-5-ghz-channel-above-2-4-ghz), but I have none of those options that are shown in the examples, such as choosing the BAND. Here is what I can see, there are really no options.

[top level of Wi-Fi Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TaAAC.png)

[Detail on the Network, shows both frequencies, but no option to choose them](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YsJTS.png)

Referring back to that other page for forcing to 5GHz, I was able to pull some information from a test machine set up in my house with a mesh network consisting of 4 nodes.

I ran this `iwlist wlp2s0 scanning`. I took the results and pared it down to this resulting list.

**Cell 01 - Address: 90:9A:4A:2E:8A:9F**
Channel:36
Frequency:5.18 GHz (Channel 36)
Quality=54/70  Signal level=-56 dBm
Encryption key:on
ESSID:"APR"

**Cell 02 - Address: 3C:84:6A:68:00:5B**
Channel:36
Frequency:5.18 GHz (Channel 36)
Quality=36/70  Signal level=-74 dBm
Encryption key:on
ESSID:"APR"

**Cell 03 - Address: 3C:84:6A:68:21:F2**
Channel:4
Frequency:2.427 GHz (Channel 4)
Quality=40/70  Signal level=-70 dBm
Encryption key:on
ESSID:"APR"

**Cell 04 - Address: 3C:84:6A:68:00:5A**
Channel:4
Frequency:2.427 GHz (Channel 4)
Quality=51/70  Signal level=-59 dBm
Encryption key:on
ESSID:"APR"

**Cell 05 - Address: 3C:84:6A:68:27:07**
Channel:36
Frequency:5.18 GHz (Channel 36)
Quality=58/70  Signal level=-52 dBm
Encryption key:on
ESSID:"APR"

**Cell 07 - Address: 3C:84:6A:68:21:F3**
Channel:36
Frequency:5.18 GHz (Channel 36)
Quality=30/70  Signal level=-80 dBm
Encryption key:on
ESSID:"APR"

**Cell 08 - Address: 90:9A:4A:2E:8A:9E**
Channel:4
Frequency:2.427 GHz (Channel 4)
Quality=70/70  Signal level=-36 dBm
Encryption key:on
ESSID:"APR"

**Cell 10 - Address: 3C:84:6A:68:27:06**
Channel:4
Frequency:2.427 GHz (Channel 4)
Quality=35/70  Signal level=-75 dBm
Encryption key:on
ESSID:"APR"

So I assume that there would be a command that I can set a preference as to which I would like to choose. I also assume that in this instance, I want to choose CELL 8, as it appears to have the highest quality at 2.4GHZ.

Assuming those two things, If I can remote into a computer, as it is on the other side of the continent, I could do this safely without loosing connectivity, once it switches? I can run tests locally to test.

Thank you!

Comment: I think you want to set the BSSID to 3C:84:6A:68:21:F2 to try the one 2,4 GHz AP, that would be in the identidy tab

Comment: Possibly helpful: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1192099/19-10-ubuntu-automatically-connects-to-a-weaker-wi-fi/1192112#1192112 Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: Thank you both @Jeremy31 and chili555. Using what I learned from the link and the suggestion for the Identity tab, I think I was able to force it. Being so new to this Linux side of stuff, it takes me many reads and rereads of information to piece it together. I found this command helpful in visualizing the networks

`nmcli -f in-use,ssid,freq,bssid,signal,rate,bars  dev wifi`

Answer (score 0):

Using the information from @Jeremy31 and @Chili555, I was able to find a simpler command.

`nmcli -f in-use,ssid,freq,bssid,signal,rate,bars  dev wifi`

[image]

This brought back a simple list of all wireless access points with their frequencies, and the needed BSSID. Armed with this info, in the second tab of the dialog box IDENTITY when you click on the details of the network:

[image]

you can [enter the BSSID](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hMTa4.png) and lock it to that access point. I think this solves my issues.

Comment: I have removed the images which have a reference to pornography, perhaps create  more suitable images and repost?

Comment: @andrew.46 I was unable to get the offending network name changed at the location, but I was able to get a guest network created so I could make "clean examples" I also went and blurred the offending name, as it still shows in the examples as the network is still there. I also fixed the image in the initial request. I am still learning the etiquette and mores of this group, so I understand removing the images, but do you know if the down vote on the answer was because of that, or because the answer is wrong?

Comment: Thanks for that. I have made the first 2 images inline, the 3rd image seems to be a dupe of the first? I am not sure of the downvotes, it is usually better for the downvoter to leave an explanatory comment...